# How to change the alpha value of spriteNode?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene

I am changing the `alpha` value of `spriteNode` like this,

```
if (firstBody.node?.name)! == "Player" && secondBody.node?.name == "Alpha 1" {

        var item: SKSpriteNode?
        item = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BG")
        item!.alpha = 0.1

        score += 1
        scoreLabel?.text = String(score)
}
```

This is mentioned in the documentation (use `node.alpha = value`), but I am not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: You are changing an instance node that is not on the scene!

Comment: Is this in `didBegin(contact:)` i.e. sprite-Kit collision detection? How do you know if firstBody is the player and secondBody is "Alpha1"? They might be reversed. Also, what is this new sprite `item` that you are trying to fade? It's not on screen so you won't see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can fade the alpha by using a Action, I have left an example below.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {  
  var player: SKSpriteNode!  

  override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        player = SKSpriteNode(color: .purple, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))      
        player.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
        self.addChild(player)            
    }

    func fadePlayer() {    
        let fadeAlpha = SKAction.fadeAlpha(to: 0.1, duration: 1.0)
        self.run(fadeAlpha)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        fadePlayer()
    }

}
```

When a touch begins the SpriteNode will fade out to the alpha value you insert, it will fade out gradually during a time you insert in the duration also, This action fades the SpriteNode's alpha to 0.1 gradually over 1 second.